# Ошибка создания View в Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, windows-10

столкнулся с проблемой создания View в Entity. Работаю в VS17.

Проблема заключается в слишком длинном имени пути (ограничение на 259 символов)

Пробовал решить эту проблему следующим образом:

1.прошел по следующему пути в `win+r regedit`: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` Установил значение в 1.

2.пробовал также через групповые политики `(Win+R\gpedit.msc) Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths` Включил

К сожалению это не решило мою проблему и все равно при попытки создания view (list-view) выдает мне ошибку

> There was an error running the selected code generator:'The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters'

И какого черта вообще существует такое ограничение в 2019 году?

Comment: Совместимость, чтоб её... Это в мире маргинальных ОС можно сделать ломающее изменение, а в Винде всё навека. / А вы комп перезагружали после внесения изменений? / Как вариант, перенесите проект поближе к корню диска, чтобы путь был покороче.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov конечно же перезагружал, а вот проект к корню переносить не пробовал, спасибо за наводку